# A small generic array in C

Tags: c, array, generics, template, type-safety

The generic arrays in C I found on the net used either of these methods:

- The preprocesser with `#define` and `#include` (a lot of repetition and different names when declaring multiple types, but type-safe).
- `void *`-pointers (no type safety).
- `void *`-pointers and callbacks that fetch specific datatypes from the pointers (troublesome since every datatype needs callbacks and slow due to a lot of callback calls when copying multiple values).
- Typed pointers for direct access and casting them to `void **` or `char **` in general array functions (generic and partly type-safe), actually results in UB since you can't simply alter any pointer to a pointer by dereferencing it as `void **` or `char **` as they may not share the same internal representation.

I wanted it more `template`-like, without much preparation, only one name for many types and also without repeating the datatype on every push/pop/etc, still type-safe and also standard compliant (no implementation-defined/undefined behaviour or GNU extensions).

I came up with a struct with a typed pointer and heavy preprocesser use, a short example code looks like this:

```
struct ary(int) a;

ary_init(&a, 0);
ary_push(&a, 30);
ary_push(&a, 20);
ary_push(&a, 10);
ary_sort(&a, ary_cb_cmpint);
ary_reverse(&a);
ary_release(&a);
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/GiveMeZeny/ary.c), mostly in ary.h and the rest in ary.c. Below there is the relevant part of the array with the less important functionality (`ary_insert`, `ary_sort`, `ary_unique`, ...) and predefined `comp`-/`stringify`-callbacks omitted.

I'd like to know whether it's bad designed or not useful at all, and if there are errors in the code like UB, bad idioms, etc.

**ary.h**

```
#ifndef ARY_H
#define ARY_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define ARY_GROWTH_FACTOR 2.0

/* construct/destruct the element pointed to by `buf` */
typedef void (*ary_elemcb_t)(void *buf, void *userp);

/* the same as the `qsort` comparison function */
typedef int (*ary_cmpcb_t)(const void *a, const void *b);

/* return a malloc()ed string of `buf` in `ret` and its size, or -1 */
typedef int (*ary_joincb_t)(char **ret, const void *buf);

typedef void *(*ary_xalloc_t)(void *ptr, size_t nmemb, size_t size);
typedef void (*ary_xdealloc_t)(void *ptr);

/* struct size: 6x pointers + 4x size_t's + 1x type */
#define ary(type)                                       \
        {                                               \
                struct aryb s;                          \
                size_t len;    /* number of elements */ \
                type *buf;     /* array buffer */       \
                type *ptr;                              \
                type val;                               \
        }

struct aryb {
        size_t len;
        size_t alloc;
        size_t sz;
        void *buf;
        ary_elemcb_t ctor;
        ary_elemcb_t dtor;
        void *userp;
};

/* predefined callbacks */
void ary_cb_freevoidptr(void *buf, void *userp);
void ary_cb_freecharptr(void *buf, void *userp);

int ary_cb_cmpint(const void *a, const void *b);
int ary_cb_strcmp(const void *a, const void *b);

int ary_cb_inttostr(char **ret, const void *elem);

/* forward declarations */
void ary_freebuf(struct aryb *ary);
void *ary_detach(struct aryb *ary, size_t *ret);
int ary_shrinktofit(struct aryb *ary);
void *ary_splicep(struct aryb *ary, size_t pos, size_t rlen, size_t alen);
int ary_index(struct aryb *ary, size_t *ret, size_t start, const void *data,
              ary_cmpcb_t comp);
int ary_join(struct aryb *ary, char **ret, const char *sep,
             ary_joincb_t stringify);

extern ary_xalloc_t ary_xrealloc;

/**
 * ary_init() - initialize an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the array
 * @hint: count of elements to allocate memory for
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if ary_grow() failed. Always returns
 *      1 if @hint is 0.
 *
 * Note!: Do not directly access elements that are not added to the array yet,
 *      only those with an index below @ary->len.
 */
#define ary_init(ary, hint)                                 \
        ((ary)->s.alloc = (ary)->s.len = (ary)->len = 0,    \
         (ary)->s.sz = sizeof(*(ary)->buf),                 \
         (ary)->s.ctor = (ary)->s.dtor = NULL,              \
         (ary)->s.buf = (ary)->s.userp = (ary)->buf = NULL, \
         ary_grow((ary), (hint)))

/**
 * ary_release() - release an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 *
 * All elements are removed, the buffer is released and @ary is reinitialized
 * with `ary_init(@ary, 0)`.
 */
#define ary_release(ary)                  \
        do {                              \
                ary_freebuf(&(ary)->s);   \
                (void)ary_init((ary), 0); \
        } while (0)

/**
 * ary_setcbs() - set an array's constructor and destructor
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @_ctor: routine that creates new elements
 * @_dtor: routine that removes elements
 */
#define ary_setcbs(ary, _ctor, _dtor) \
        ((ary)->s.ctor = (_ctor), (ary)->s.dtor = (_dtor), (void)0)

 /**
 * ary_setuserp() - set an array's user-pointer for the ctor/dtor
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @ptr: pointer that gets passed to the callbacks
 */
#define ary_setuserp(ary, ptr) \
        ((ary)->s.userp = (ptr), (void)0)

/**
 * ary_setinitval() - set an array's value used to initialize new elements
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @...: value that is used for new elements if @ary->ctor() is NULL
 *
 * Note!: @... is like in ary_push(). Also the init-value is left uninitialized
 *      when using ary_init(). However, it has to be specified when
 *      initializing an array with ARY_INIT().
 */
#define ary_setinitval(ary, ...) \
        ((ary)->val = (__VA_ARGS__), (void)0)

/**
 * ary_attach() - attach a buffer to an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @nbuf: pointer to a malloc()ed buffer
 * @nlen: number of elements pointed to by @nbuf
 * @nalloc: number of elements the buffer can hold
 *
 * The buffer @nbuf is henceforth owned by @ary and cannot be relied upon
 * anymore and also must not be free()d directly.
 */
#define ary_attach(ary, nbuf, nlen, nalloc)       \
        do {                                      \
                ary_freebuf(&(ary)->s);           \
                (ary)->s.buf = (ary)->buf = nbuf; \
                (ary)->s.len = (ary)->len = nlen; \
                (ary)->s.alloc = nalloc;          \
        } while (0)

/**
 * ary_detach() - detach an array's buffer
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @size: pointer that receives @ary's length, can be NULL
 *
 * A directly following ary_release() is not needed.
 *
 * Return: The array buffer of @ary. If @ary's has no allocated memory, NULL is
 *      returned. You have to free() the buffer, when you no longer need it.
 */
#define ary_detach(ary, size)                                             \
        ((ary)->ptr = (ary_detach)(&(ary)->s, (size)), (ary)->buf = NULL, \
         (ary)->len = 0, (ary)->ptr)

/**
 * ary_grow() - allocate new memory in an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @extra: count of extra elements
 *
 * Ensure that @ary can hold at least @extra more elements.
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if realloc() failed.
 */
#define ary_grow(ary, extra) \
        ((ary_grow)(&(ary)->s, (extra)) ? ((ary)->buf = (ary)->s.buf, 1) : 0)

/**
 * ary_shrinktofit() - release unused allocated memory in an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if realloc() failed. The array remains
 *      valid in either case.
 */
#define ary_shrinktofit(ary) \
        ((ary_shrinktofit)(&(ary)->s) ? ((ary)->buf = (ary)->s.buf, 1) : 0)

/**
 * ary_setlen() - set an array's length
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @nlen: new number of elements @ary holds
 *
 * If @nlen is above @ary's current length, new elements are added, either by
 * calling @ary->ctor() on them or by using the array's (possibly uninitialized)
 * init-value. Respectively, if @nlen is below @ary's current length,
 * @ary->dtor() is called on all elements above the new length.
 * However, the array is never reallocated and @nlen is truncated to not exceed
 * `@ary.len + ary_avail(@ary)`.
 */
#define ary_setlen(ary, nlen)                                                  \
        do {                                                                   \
                size_t len = (nlen), i;                                        \
                if ((ary)->s.len < len) {                                      \
                        if ((ary)->s.alloc < len)                              \
                                len = (ary)->s.alloc;                          \
                        if ((ary)->s.ctor) {                                   \
                                for (i = (ary)->s.len; i < len; i++)           \
                                        (ary)->s.ctor(&(ary)->buf[i],          \
                                                      (ary)->s.userp);         \
                        } else {                                               \
                                for (i = (ary)->s.len; i < len; i++)           \
                                        (ary)->buf[i] = (ary)->val;            \
                        }                                                      \
                } else if ((ary)->s.len > len && (ary)->s.dtor) {              \
                        for (i = len; i < (ary)->s.len; i++)                   \
                                (ary)->s.dtor(&(ary)->buf[i], (ary)->s.userp); \
                }                                                              \
                (ary)->s.len = (ary)->len = len;                               \
        } while (0)

/**
 * ary_push() - add a new element to the end of an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @...: value to push
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if ary_grow() failed.
 *
 * Note!: @... is only a single value, it's denoted as varargs in order to cope
 *      with struct-literals, additionally, it is not evaluated if ary_push()
 *      fails (so e.g. `strdup(s)` has no effect on failure).
 */
#define ary_push(ary, ...)                                                   \
        (((ary)->s.len == (ary)->s.alloc) ?                                  \
         ary_grow((ary), 1) ?                                                \
         ((ary)->buf[(ary)->len++, (ary)->s.len++] = (__VA_ARGS__), 1) : 0 : \
         ((ary)->buf[(ary)->len++, (ary)->s.len++] = (__VA_ARGS__), 1))

/**
 * ary_pushp() - add a new element slot to the end of an array (pointer)
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 *
 * Return: When successful a pointer to the new element slot, otherwise NULL if
 *      ary_grow() failed.
 */
#define ary_pushp(ary)                                      \
        (((ary)->s.len == (ary)->s.alloc) ?                 \
         ary_grow((ary), 1) ?                               \
         &(ary)->buf[(ary)->len++, (ary)->s.len++] : NULL : \
         &(ary)->buf[(ary)->len++, (ary)->s.len++])

/**
 * ary_pop() - remove the last element of an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @ret: pointer that receives the popped element's value, can be NULL
 *
 * If @ret is NULL, @ary->dtor() is called for the element to be popped.
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if there were no elements to pop.
 */
#define ary_pop(ary, ret)                                             \
        ((ary)->s.len ?                                               \
         ((void *)(ret) != NULL) ?                                    \
         (*(((void *)(ret) != NULL) ? (ret) : &(ary)->val) =          \
          (ary)->buf[--(ary)->s.len], (ary)->len--, 1) :              \
         (ary)->s.dtor ?                                              \
         ((ary)->s.dtor(&(ary)->buf[--(ary)->s.len], (ary)->s.userp), \
          (ary)->len--, 1) :                                          \
         ((ary)->s.len--, (ary)->len--, 1) : 0)

/**
 * ary_shift() - remove the first element of an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @ret: pointer that receives the shifted element's value, can be NULL
 *
 * If @ret is NULL, @ary->dtor() is called for the element to be shifted.
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if there were no elements to shift.
 */
#define ary_shift(ary, ret)                                                 \
        ((ary)->s.len ?                                                     \
         ((void *)(ret) != NULL) ?                                          \
         (*(((void *)(ret) != NULL) ? (ret) : &(ary)->val) = (ary)->buf[0], \
          memmove(&(ary)->buf[0], &(ary)->buf[1],                           \
                  --(ary)->s.len * (ary)->s.sz), (ary)->len--, 1) :         \
         (ary)->s.dtor ?                                                    \
         ((ary)->s.dtor(&(ary)->buf[0], (ary)->s.userp),                    \
          memmove(&(ary)->buf[0], &(ary)->buf[1],                           \
                  --(ary)->s.len * (ary)->s.sz), (ary)->len--, 1) :         \
         (memmove(&(ary)->buf[0], &(ary)->buf[1],                           \
                  --(ary)->s.len * (ary)->s.sz), (ary)->len--, 1) : 0)

/**
 * ary_unshift() - add a new element to the beginning of an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @...: value to unshift
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if ary_grow() failed.
 *
 * Note!: @... is like in ary_push().
 */
#define ary_unshift(ary, ...) \
        (ary_unshiftp(ary) ? (*(ary)->ptr = (__VA_ARGS__), 1) : 0)

/**
 * ary_unshiftp() - add a new element slot to the beginning of an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 *
 * Return: When successful a pointer to the new element slot, otherwise NULL if
 *      ary_grow() failed.
 */
#define ary_unshiftp(ary) \
        ary_splicep((ary), 0, 0, 1)

/**
 * ary_splice() - add/remove elements from an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @pos: index at which to add/remove
 * @rlen: number of elements to remove
 * @data: pointer to new elements
 * @dlen: number of new elements to add
 *
 * Return: When successful 1, otherwise 0 if there were new elements to add but
 *      ary_grow() failed (the array remains unchanged in this case).
 */
#define ary_splice(ary, pos, rlen, data, dlen)                        \
        (ary_splicep((ary), (pos), (rlen), (dlen)) ?                  \
         (memcpy((ary)->ptr, (data) ? (void *)(data) : (void *)(ary), \
                 (data) ? (dlen) * (ary)->s.sz : 0), 1) : 0)

/**
 * ary_splicep() - add element slots/remove elements from an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @pos: index at which to add/remove
 * @rlen: number of elements to remove
 * @alen: number of new element slots to add
 *
 * Return: When successful a pointer to the first new element slot (position of
 *      the last removed element), otherwise NULL if there were new elements
 *      slots to allocate but ary_grow() failed (the array remains unchanged in
 *      this case).
 */
#define ary_splicep(ary, pos, rlen, alen)                                     \
        (((ary)->ptr = (ary_splicep)(&(ary)->s, (pos), (rlen), (alen))) ?     \
         ((ary)->buf = (ary)->s.buf, (ary)->len = (ary)->s.len, (ary)->ptr) : \
         NULL)

/**
 * ary_index() - get the first occurrence of an element in an array
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @ret: pointer that receives the element's position, can be NULL
 * @start: position to start looking from
 * @data: pointer to the data to look for
 * @comp: comparison function, if NULL then memcmp() is used
 *
 * Return: When successful 1 and @ret is set to the position of the element
 *      found, otherwise 0 and @ret is uninitialized.
 */
#define ary_index(ary, ret, start, data, comp)                       \
        ((ary)->ptr = (data), (ary_index)(&(ary)->s, (ret), (start), \
                                          (ary)->ptr, (comp)))

/**
 * ary_join() - join all elements of an array into a string
 * @ary: typed pointer to the initialized array
 * @ret: pointer that receives a pointer to the new string
 * @sep: pointer to the null-terminated separator
 * @stringify: stringify function, if NULL then @ary is assumed to be a char *-
 *      array
 *
 * Return: When successful length of @ret, otherwise -1 with `*@ret == NULL` if
 *      realloc() failed. You have to free() *@ret, when you no longer need it.
 */
#define ary_join(ary, ret, sep, stringify) \
        (ary_join)(&(ary)->s, (ret), (sep), (stringify))

static inline int (ary_grow)(struct aryb *ary, size_t extra)
{
        const double factor = ARY_GROWTH_FACTOR;
        size_t alloc;
        void *buf;

        if (ary->len + extra <= ary->alloc)
                return 1;
        if (ary->alloc * factor < ary->len + extra)
                alloc = ary->len + extra;
        else
                alloc = ary->alloc * factor;
        buf = ary_xrealloc(ary->buf, alloc, ary->sz);
        if (!buf)
                return 0;
        ary->alloc = alloc;
        ary->buf = buf;
        return 1;
}

/* .... */

#endif /* ARY_H */
```

**ary.c**

```
#include "ary.h"

static void *ary_xrealloc_builtin(void *ptr, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
        return realloc(ptr, nmemb * size);
}

ary_xalloc_t ary_xrealloc = ary_xrealloc_builtin;
static ary_xdealloc_t ary_xfree = free;

void ary_cb_freevoidptr(void *buf, void *userp)
{
        (void)userp;
        ary_xfree(*(void **)buf);
}

void ary_cb_freecharptr(void *buf, void *userp)
{
        (void)userp;
        ary_xfree(*(char **)buf);
}

int ary_cb_cmpint(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        int x = *(const int *)a, y = *(const int *)b;

        return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0;
}

int ary_cb_strcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

static const size_t snprintf_bufsize = 32;

int ary_cb_inttostr(char **ret, const void *elem)
{
        if (!(*ret = ary_xrealloc(NULL, snprintf_bufsize, 1)))
                return -1;
        return snprintf(*ret, snprintf_bufsize, "%d", *(int *)elem);
}

void ary_freebuf(struct aryb *ary)
{
        if (ary->len && ary->dtor) {
                ary_elemcb_t dtor = ary->dtor;
                char *elem = ary->buf;
                void *userp = ary->userp;
                size_t i;

                for (i = ary->len; i--; elem += ary->sz)
                        dtor(elem, userp);
        }
        ary_xfree(ary->buf);
}

void *(ary_detach)(struct aryb *ary, size_t *ret)
{
        void *buf;

        (ary_shrinktofit)(ary);
        buf = ary->buf;
        if (ret)
                *ret = ary->len;
        ary->alloc = ary->len = 0;
        ary->buf = NULL;
        return buf;
}

int (ary_shrinktofit)(struct aryb *ary)
{
        void *buf;

        if (ary->alloc == ary->len)
                return 1;
        if (ary->len) {
                buf = ary_xrealloc(ary->buf, ary->len, ary->sz);
                if (!buf)
                        return 0;
        } else {
                ary_xfree(ary->buf);
                buf = NULL;
        }
        ary->alloc = ary->len;
        ary->buf = buf;
        return 1;
}

void *(ary_splicep)(struct aryb *ary, size_t pos, size_t rlen, size_t alen)
{
        char *buf;

        if (pos > ary->len)
                pos = ary->len;
        if (rlen > ary->len - pos)
                rlen = ary->len - pos;
        if (alen > rlen && !(ary_grow)(ary, alen - rlen))
                return NULL;
        buf = (char *)ary->buf + (pos * ary->sz);
        if (rlen && ary->dtor) {
                ary_elemcb_t dtor = ary->dtor;
                char *elem = buf;
                void *userp = ary->userp;
                size_t i;

                for (i = rlen; i--; elem += ary->sz)
                        dtor(elem, userp);
        }
        if (rlen != alen && pos < ary->len)
                memmove(buf + (alen * ary->sz), buf + (rlen * ary->sz),
                        (ary->len - pos - rlen) * ary->sz);
        ary->len = ary->len - rlen + alen;
        return buf;
}

int (ary_index)(struct aryb *ary, size_t *ret, size_t start, const void *data,
                ary_cmpcb_t comp)
{
        size_t i;
        char *elem = (char *)ary->buf + (start * ary->sz);

        for (i = start; i < ary->len; i++, elem += ary->sz) {
                if (comp ? !comp(elem, data) : !memcmp(elem, data, ary->sz)) {
                        if (ret)
                                *ret = i;
                        return 1;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}

int (ary_join)(struct aryb *ary, char **ret, const char *sep,
               ary_joincb_t stringify)
{
        struct ary_char strbuf;
        char *elem = (char *)ary->buf, *tmp;
        size_t seplen = sep ? strlen(sep) : 0, i, len;
        int tmplen, tmpret;

        if (!ary_init(&strbuf, 1024))
                goto error;
        for (i = 0; i < ary->len; i++, elem += ary->sz) {
                if (stringify) {
                        tmplen = stringify(&tmp, elem);
                        if (tmplen > 0) {
                                tmpret = ary_splice(&strbuf, strbuf.len, 0,
                                                    tmp, tmplen);
                                ary_xfree(tmp);
                                if (!tmpret)
                                        goto error;
                        } else if (!tmplen) {
                                ary_xfree(tmp);
                        }
                } else {
                        tmp = *(char **)elem;
                        if (!tmp)
                                continue;
                        if (!ary_splice(&strbuf, strbuf.len, 0, tmp,
                                        strlen(tmp)))
                                goto error;
                }
                if (seplen) {
                        if (!ary_splice(&strbuf, strbuf.len, 0, sep, seplen))
                                goto error;
                }
        }
        if (!strbuf.len) {
                if (!(*ret = strdup("")))
                        goto error;
                return 0;
        }
        ary_setlen(&strbuf, strbuf.len - seplen + 1);
        strbuf.buf[strbuf.len - 1] = '\0';
        ary_shrinktofit(&strbuf);
        *ret = ary_detach(&strbuf, &len);
        return (int)len;

error:
        ary_release(&strbuf);
        *ret = NULL;
        return -1;
}

/* .... */
```

Comment: The `/* ... */` suggests that you've omitted some of the code. Is the entire project contained in the question as it is? If so, what's been snipped?

Comment: I have edited my question to answer yours.

Answer (score 2):

Some lesser observations,

1. With heavy use of macros,, care should be applied to insure exactly one use of a macro argument as the macro arguments could be complex and have side effects which only should be evaluated once.

   ```
   //#define ary_attach(ary, nbuf, nlen, nalloc)       \
   //        do {                                      \
   //                ary_freebuf(&(ary)->s);           \
   //                 (ary)->s.buf = (ary)->buf = nbuf;\
   // ...
   #define ary_attach(ary, nbuf, nlen, nalloc)       \
           do {                                      \
             struct aryb *ary__ = ary;  // add       \
             ary_freebuf(&ary__->s);                 \
             ary__->s.buf = ary__->buf = nbuf;       \
    ...
   ```
2. Avoid magic numbers like 32.  Why 32?

   ```
   // static const size_t snprintf_bufsize = 32;

   // Maximum buffer size of  string version of `int` log10(bitwidth)
   // Other formula are more precise, but better than guessing buffer needs.
   static const size_t snprintf_bufsize = sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3;

   int ary_cb_inttostr(char **ret, const void *elem) {
     if (!(*ret = ary_xrealloc(NULL, snprintf_bufsize, 1)))
       return -1;
     return snprintf(*ret, snprintf_bufsize, "%d", *(int *)elem);
   }
   ```
3. As `free(NULL)` is OK, IMO, any free-like function should also handle `NULL`.

   ```
   void ary_freebuf(struct aryb *ary) {
     if (ary == NULL) return; // add
     if (ary->len && ary->dtor) {
   ```
4. `ary.c` should include files like `strcmp.h` and not count on `#include "ary.h"` to have included them.
5. Consider simpler code, as below and in other places.

   ```
   // size_t seplen = sep ? strlen(sep) : 0, i, len;
   size_t seplen = sep ? strlen(sep) : 0;
   size_t i, len;
   ```
6. Without clear code understanding, I have a bit concern about `strbuf.buf[strbuf.len - 1]`.  Should `strbuf.len == 0`, disastrous result would occur.
7. Uncertain: Comments on # lines is not portable.  I'll have to research this.

   ```
   #endif /* ARY_H */
   ```
8. Be careful about  `ary_xrealloc()`, which calls `realloc()`.  Should `ary->len == 0` , return `NULL` is not an out-of-memory

   ```
   buf = ary_xrealloc(ary->buf, ary->len, ary->sz);
   // if (!buf) return 0;
   if (buf == NULL && ary->len > 0 && ary->sz > 0) return 0;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your observations.
1. This works for `struct aryb`, but not for `ary` itself as it's generic. So you can't guarantee that `ary`is always evaluated only once, also many macros are one-liners to return a value, a `do {} while`-construct wouldn't be possible in this case. That's why I included the note "It's not safe to pass parameters that have side effects".
2. I chose 32 because I have multiple callbacks like `inttostr`, `doubletostr`, `voidptrtostr`and I thought that this would be a reasonable size for their buffers.

Comment: 3. However, `ary_freebuf` frees the array's buffer, not the array itself. So in `free(NULL)` the `NULL` would be the array's buffer, not the array itself, and this works because it's simply forwarded to `ary_xfree(ary->buf)`.
6. That's what the `if (!strbuf.len) {` is for.
I'll look into the rest, thanks.

Comment: @netcat #6 - I did not notice `if (!strbuf.len) {`, that part of code is good.  Confident `strbuf.len + 1 >=  seplen` alwasy true in  `ary_setlen(&strbuf, strbuf.len - seplen + 1);`?

Comment: Yes, because if there are elements and a separator, then strbuf ends with the separator and it gets cut off with that line.